# AVPlayerItemVideoOutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime gives incorrect CVPixelBufferRef on iOS for particular video

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayeritem, core-video, cvpixelbuffer

Have you met the problem when for the same video `copyPixelBufferForItemTime` is incorrect on iOS?

I have `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput`, linked to appropriate `AVPlayerItem`.
I call `copyPixelBufferForItemTime`, receive `CVPixelBufferRef` and then retrieve OpenGL texture from it.

```
CVPixelBufferRef pb = [_playerVideoOutput copyPixelBufferForItemTime:currentTime itemTimeForDisplay:nil];
```

For this [sample video](https://www.shutterstock.com/video/clip-7003588?irgwc=1&utm_medium=Affiliate&utm_campaign=Oxford%20Media%20Solutions&utm_source=51471) there's bug with CVPixelBufferRef:

```
int bpr = (int)CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pb);
int width_real = (int)CVPixelBufferGetWidth(pb);
int width_working = (int)CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pb)/4;
```

*Mac output*:
          bpr = **2400**
   width_real = 596
width_working = **600**

*iOS output*: 
          bpr = **2432**
   width_real = 596
width_working = **608**

How it's rendered on iOS:
[image]

How it's rendered on Mac:
[image]

`CVPixelBufferGetPixelFormatType` returns `BGRA` on both platforms.

**Edit**
When creating texture on iOS, I read data from pixel buffer via `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress`  and use provided size `CVPixelBufferGetWidth`/`CVPixelBufferGetHeight`:

```
- (GLuint)createTextureFromMovieFrame:(CVPixelBufferRef)movieFrame
{
    int bufferWidth = (int) CVPixelBufferGetWidth(movieFrame);
    int bufferHeight = (int) CVPixelBufferGetHeight(movieFrame);

    // Upload to texture
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(movieFrame, 0);

    CVOpenGLTextureRef texture=0;
    GLuint tex = 0;

#if TARGET_OS_IOS==1
    void * data = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(movieFrame);
    CVReturn err = 0;
    tex = algotest::MyGL::createRGBATexture(bufferWidth, bufferHeight, data, algotest::MyGL::KLinear);

#else
    CVReturn err = CVOpenGLTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                          getGlobalTextureCache(), movieFrame, 0, &texture);
#endif

    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(movieFrame, 0);

    return tex;
}
```

So `width_working` is just for debug. As it mismatch `width_real`, and passing neither `width_working` not `width_real` doesn't work, I suppose that it's a bug with pixel buffer.

Comment: It looks like you're mishandling the per-line padding in the iOS case (when `width_real*4 != CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(pb)`. Can you show how you're creating the texture?  What exactly are you doing with `width_working`?

Comment: @RhythmicFistman It seems I misnamed the variables. :)  `width_working` is for debug. Updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pixel buffers have per-line padding pixels on both iOS and mac, presumably for alignment reasons. The difference is that the mac `CVOpenGLTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage` function understands this, while the iOS `createRGBATexture` function can not, not without a bytes-per-row argument.

You could either include the padding pixels in the width, and crop them out later:

```
tex = algotest::MyGL::createRGBATexture(CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(movieFrame)/4, bufferHeight, data, algotest::MyGL::KLinear);
```

Or you could use `CVOpenGLESTextureCache`, the iOS equivalent of `CVOpenGLTextureCache` and replace `createRGBATexture()` with `CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreateTextureFromImage()`. Then your mac & iOS code would be similar & the iOS code might even run faster as texture caches on iOS can avoid redundant copying of texture data.